# searching a column form pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I have 3 models Eg: Model-1, Model-2, Model-3.

Model-2 and Model-3 has many to many relationship,
So i'm keeping one pivot table like Model-2_Model-3.

Model-1 is has one relationship with model-2 and i'm listing all the data from model-1,

I need to search one column from pivot table for listing Model-1.

For Eg:

```
$data = Model-1::with('Model-2')->get();
```

I need to search Model-1 Using pivot table (Model-2_Model-3).

I return pivot connection code already. Pivot is working very well.

Answer (score 1):

You can query pivot table with `wherePivot()`

```
Model-1::with('Model-2')->wherePivot('field_name', $value)->get();
```

If the pivot values are not added, you need to add it as `withPivot('field_name')`

Comment: Model-2 and Model-3 is only having many to many relation. so I need to search on Model-2_Model-3 pivot table. and should be filtered by Model-1.

Answer (score 0):

You may like to use `contains`, as for many to many relationship you will get collection of second model something like `$user->roles`, so here you can check if `$user->roles->contains('field_name')`. as well as `$user->roles()->wherePivot('role_id', 1)->get()->isEmpty()` or `$user->roles()->wherePivot('role_id', 1)->get()` depending on your requirement.

Comment: This solution is finding data directly from a pivot table. Eg: When Model-2 and Model-3 connected we can use this method. But my scenario is
Main table is Model-1 and Model-1 is connecting Model-2, Model-2 and Model-3 having many to many relation. I need to filter Model-1 using Model-2_Model-3 pivot table.

I tried whereHas , But its not working. using whereHas we can filer Model-1 using Model-2 only. Nested whereHas is not working.

Comment: In that case too, you will be having a hasManyThrough relationship, so you will get a collection again, so I think you can use contains, also I would like to see your whereaHas clause you have tried, then may be I will be able to help you.

Comment: $data = Model-1::whereHas('model-2', function ($q) {
                $q->whereHas('model-3', function($qr){
                    $qr->where('model-3.id', 1);
                });
            })->wherePivot('type','=', '1')->get();

Comment: @midhunprakash If that solved your problem, you should post this as answer.

Comment: @midhunprakash Can you try ` $roles = Model-1::with('Model-2')->whereHas('model-3.id', function ($query) {
                $query->where('model-3.id', 1); 
   });
        })->get();` and let me know if you are getting any error or correct result?